# How do I add elevation (shadow) to my BottomNavigationView. It doesn't come by default

Tags: android, material-design, bottomnavigationview

I tried setting elevation from xml and programmatically both. But nothing works.[image]

Comment: Have you upgraded to 25.0.1? Elevation was mentioned as a fixed issue for that release https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/revisions.html

Comment: If you have upgraded to 25.0.1 but it still doesnt work may be it is because it was not supported for older versions devices!!

Comment: I am using 25.1.0 and still not seeing a default elevation.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 36):

It only works if you set white as android:background in the BottomNavigationView.

This is my code and it's working:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:elevation="8dp"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/bottom_color_state"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/bottom_color_state"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.52"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />
```

Answer (score 3):

I got the solution. You need to add background attribute along with elevation else it wont show the shadow.

Comment: Post your code for solution which is worked for you. thanks.

Comment: Please show your code for this solution, because it is not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is the only solution that worked for me:

```
val background = bottomNavigation.background
if (background is MaterialShapeDrawable) {
    background.shadowCompatibilityMode = SHADOW_COMPAT_MODE_ALWAYS
}
```

as suggested here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/124153644#comment2

Answer (score 1):

For those who are interested, I also managed to get some shadow using a background drawable. However, I had to use the color white otherwise it doesn't work...

It can be useful if you want to do angles like I do.

**drawable/gnt_rounded_corners_shape.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <solid android:color="@android:color/white"/>

  <corners android:bottomRightRadius="0dp"
      android:bottomLeftRadius="0dp"
      android:topLeftRadius="16dp"
      android:topRightRadius="16dp" />
</shape>
```

and inside **layout/main_activity.xml**

```xml
    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigation"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/gnt_rounded_corners_shape"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        />
```

result :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if you're not using `CoordinateLayout` with `BottomNavigationBar` you could just wrap your navigation with a `CardView` or `MaterialCardView` and set `cardElevation` to what you want and `cardCornerRadius` to zero.