# Add elevation to BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, android-support-library, bottomnavigationview

Here's what my bottom navigation bar in XML looks like:

```
<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
      android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:background="@android:color/white"
      app:itemBackground="@color/primary"
      app:elevation="8dp"
      app:menu="@menu/main_activity_bottom_nav"/>
```

If I remove `app:itemBackground="@color/primary"`, the elevation shows properly, but the moment I add that back in, it disappears.

Comment: Maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40766722/how-do-i-add-elevation-shadow-to-my-bottomnavigationview-it-doesnt-come-by-d) could be helpful.

Comment: I came across that and if you see my code I actually made the background white

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not use the `app:itemBackground` property, but the color that you set as itemBackground.

If I change my `app:itemBackground` color to white, it works fine, and I can show the shadow above and bottom of the BottomNavigationView. But if I use my primary color (blue), I can see the shadow only on the bottom of my BottomNavigationView.

I think that the easiest way to solve this problem, is **create your own shadow and set it above of your BottomNavigationView**. It's very simple. This [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41650778/android-bottom-navigation-bar-with-drop-shadow) describes what you have to do.

If you encounter some problems, let a comment below.

I hope that this answer can help you!!

Good luck!!

Comment: yea, that's actually what i ended up doing, but i was hoping someone would know why setting that messes things up